# Application CacheManager conflicting with dependency's own cache

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on an application with a caching mechanism implemented.
A CacheManager bean is implemented like this:

```
@Bean (name = "applicationCacheManager")
    public CacheManager applicationCacheManager() throws URISyntaxException {
        EhcacheCachingProvider provider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider();
        javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager(
                getClass().getResource("/ehcache.xml").toURI(),
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }
```

with it's ehcache.xml and application.properties properly configured the cached is used on a method like this:

```
@Cacheable(cacheManager = "applicationCacheManager", value = "mCache", key = "#mKey")
    public String getKey(String mKey) {
        return getResponse();
    }
```

This implementation worked so far without issues (there is also a custom logger defined in a separate class that log all interaction with the cache)
Now I had to import another custom library as a dependancy and it's here that the troubles with the cache started.
At application start i have an error like:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager'
> available: expected single matching bean but found 2:
> applicationCacheManager,libraryCache

Great, nothing i can do with the library but i manage to figure out a way to handle both CacheManagers by defining a Primary CacheManager like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class DelegatingCacheManager implements CacheManager {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("applicationCacheManager")
    private CacheManager applicationCacheManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("libraryCache")
    private CacheManager libraryCache;

    @Override
    public Cache getCache(String name) {
        if ("secondCache".equals(name)) {
            return applicationCacheManager.getCache(name);
        } else if("mCache".equals(name)) {
            return applicationCacheManager.getCache(name);
        } else {
            return libraryCache.getCache(name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> getCacheNames() {
        List<String> cacheNames = new ArrayList<>();
        cacheNames.addAll(applicationCacheManager.getCacheNames());
        cacheNames.addAll(libraryCache.getCacheNames());
        return cacheNames;
    }
}
```

(mCache and secondChace are labels used in my application to cache different variables)
and as beans these:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager applicationCacheManager() throws URISyntaxException {
    EhcacheCachingProvider provider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider();
    javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager(
            getClass().getResource("/ehcache.xml").toURI(),
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public CacheManager cacheManager(DelegatingCacheManager delegatingCacheManager) {
    return delegatingCacheManager;
}
```

With this implementation my cache mechanism started working again but I've no idea if the library's own cache will be working (id doesn't log cache activities as far as i know)
The question is: Is this solution sufficient robust or there is a better way for making these two CacheManager beans coexist?
Thank you, I hope this question meets the standard of the platform.